# Changing the DPI in a JPEG without re-encoding? with ImageMagick or something else

Tags: metadata, imagemagick, jpeg, dpi, exiftool

Sometimes I have image files which I want to contain a certain DPI setting. Note that I mean just the DPI value, i.e. just the value in the image's metadata. I don't want to resize the actual image. So for example a higher DPI would result in a smaller size in centimeters, and the same amount of pixels.

I know I can set or change an image's DPI using ImageMagick `convert` with the `-density` parameter, but this will re-encode the image. I want to avoid that.

Is there a way, with ImageMagick or something else (e.g. ExifTool or something) to explicitly set a JPEG's DPI value without changing the actual compressed image contents itself?

Note that I'm using OS X and looking for a command line tool to do this (I want to use it in shell scripts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

You command would be:
`exiftool -XResolution=# -YResolution=# FileOrDir`
Change the hashmark to the new DPI number.  This command will make backups of each file, which you can avoid by adding `-overwrite_original`.  Related is `-ResolutionUnit` which can be set to `None`, `inches`, or `cm`.

Comment: Another option is:
-jfif:Xresolution=300 -jfif:Yresolution=300

(suggested by the author of ExifTool here): http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=2164.0)

Comment: for 600dpi PNG files: `exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -PixelsPerUnitX=23607 -PixelsPerUnitY=23607 *.png`

Comment: @MattSephton Isn't it 600*1000/25.4 = 23622? Why 23607?

Comment: You're correct, it should be 23622. I just confirmed using Photoshop to save a 600dpi PNG. I have no recollection of this answer never mind how I came up with the other value.

Comment: How to deal with Adobe JPEGs with APP14 marker?

Comment: @mmj Deal with them in what way?  Do you have a jpg with resolution information in the APP14 block?  If so, then it would be appreciated if you could post an example in the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/) because the exiftool author has only found [limited data](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/JPEG.html#Adobe) in the APP14 block, which does not include resolution data.